# Cambiar valor que se muestra en datatable jqeury laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

tengo en mi vista un datatable que lleno con datos de la base de datos via ajax, me carga la informacion muy bien, pero una de las columnas que debo mostrar es un valor booleano, por lo tanto se muestra 0 y 1 segun corresponda y quiero cambiar la visualizacion, que en lugar de los valores se muestre SI, NO...

Con este codigo juery/ajax en la vista obtengo los datos del datatable:

```
 $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          serverSide: true,
          ajax: "{{ route('servicio.index') }}",
          columns: [
              {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
              {data: 'servicio', name: 'servicio'},
              {data: 'observaciones', name: 'observaciones'},
              {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
              {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: true, searchable: true},
            ],
            "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
            "zeroRecords": "No hay Registros por mostrar",
            "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "paginate":{
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous" : "Anterior"
            },
         }
         });
```

La tabla html:

```
<table class="table table-striper data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Servicio</th>
                    <th>Observaciones</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Y la funcion en el controlador:

```
 public function index(Request $request){
        $servicio = Servicio::select('status')->get();
        //return view('servicio.index', compact('servicio'));
       // return view('mantenedor.servicio');

       if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Servicio::latest()->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editProduct">Editar</a>';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
            }
            return view('mantenedor.servicio', compact('servicio')); //data
    }
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: Simple, usa un operador ternario

Comment: Hola @BetaM, leyendo soble los operadores ternarios como me comentas, estoy intentando con esta linea:             {data: 'seriado' , "<label id=''>". ((data:'seriado'  == '0')? 'echo "ACTIVO";' : 'echo "INACTIVO";') . "</label>"},
 pero ya no carga mas el datatable

Comment: En el frontend lo puedes hacer en la propiedad render de la columna `{ data: 'seriado', render: function (data, type, row) { return data ? 'ACTIVO' : 'INACTIVO'; } }`